# Fully updating DB table with Prisma (TypeScript)

Tags: database, typescript

I'm often updating the `Pokemon` model with more detail. This detail is then sent to the UI to be displayed in the new sections I add over time.

Since there are currently 1302 pokémon entries in the PokéAPI, I thought it would be more polite to not just request everything all at once. Instead I'm trying to fetch data for all pokémon names (can be done in one request), then grab data for 50 pokémons. Finally, I wait 10 seconds and then repeat.

The below function performs this "update", which is really about emptying the `Pokemon` table and re-populating it with more complete data taken from the [PokéAPI](https://pokeapi.co/). This code segment is ran when opening the UI:

```
/**
 * Replace current DB data with entirely new data from the PokéAPI.
 * Specify a step to limit the number of 'pokemon' and 'pokemon-species' queries
 * performed at any given time.
 */
export async function populateWithFullPokemonDetails(step: number) {
  // just in case the source gets updated with more than the current 1302 pokémon entries
  const ALL_POKEMON_WITH_LEEWAY = 2000;

  // start from where we left off
  const currentData = await prismadb.pokemon.findMany();

  const pokemonURLs = await fetcher(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=${ALL_POKEMON_WITH_LEEWAY}`)
    .then(({ results }) => results.map(({ url }: { url: string }) => url));

  if (!Array.isArray(pokemonURLs)) {
    return [];
  }

  /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
  for (let i = currentData.length; i < pokemonURLs.length; i += step) {
    const pokemonEntries = (await Promise.all(
      pokemonURLs.slice(i, i + step).map(fetcher),
    ))
      // make sure `this` is PokemonBuilder otherwise this fails
      .filter(PokemonBuilder.Check.bind(PokemonBuilder));

    // promise returns [pokemon, pokemonSpecies] tuples
    const pokemonAndSpeciesTuples = (
      await Promise.all(
        pokemonEntries.map(p => fetcher(p.species.url)
          .then(s => (PokemonSpecies.Check(s) ? [p, s] as const : []))),
      )
    ).filter(Boolean);

    await Promise.all(pokemonAndSpeciesTuples.map(([p, s]) => {
      // convert to format used in DB
      const pokemon = {
        id: p.id,
        abilities: p.abilities.map(({ ability }) => ability.name),
        baseExperience: p.base_experience,
        height: p.height,
        isDefault: p.is_default,
        name: p.name,
        order: p.order,
        sprite: p.sprites.front_default,
        type1: p.types[0]?.type.name || '',
        type2: p.types[1]?.type.name || '',
        weight: p.weight,
      };

      // forms, genera, names and stats are all related to the current pokemon
      // we use a transaction to make sure all the relevant data exist together in the DB
      return prismadb.$transaction([
        prismadb.pokemon.create({ data: pokemon }),
        prismadb.form.createMany({
          data: p.forms.map(({ name, url }) => ({
            pokemonId: p.id, name, url,
          })),
        }),
        prismadb.genus.createMany({
          data: s.genera.map(({ genus, language: { name } }) => ({
            pokemonId: p.id, genus, language: name,
          })),
        }),
        prismadb.name.createMany({
          data: s.names.map(({ name, language }) => ({
            pokemonId: p.id, name, language: language.name,
          })),
        }),
        prismadb.stat.createMany({
          data: p.stats.map(({ base_stat: baseStat, effort, stat: { name } }) => ({
            pokemonId: p.id, baseStat, effort, name,
          })),
        }),
      ]);
    }));

    // wait 10 seconds
    await sleep(10000);
  }

  // get all updated pokemon entries back
  return prismadb.pokemon.findMany();
}
```

`sleep` (used at the bottom):

```
async function sleep(delay: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, delay); });
}
```

Prism model relations:

- Form: one pokémon to many forms
- Genus: many pokémons (base + evolutions) to many genera (one per language)*
- Name: one pokémon to many names (one per language)
- Stat: one pokémon to many stats

*Here implemented as one pokémon to many genera for simplicity

```
model Pokemon {
  id             Int      @id
  abilities      String[]
  baseExperience Int      @default(0)
  forms          Form[]
  genera         Genus[]
  height         Int      @default(0)
  isDefault      Boolean  @default(true)
  name           String   @unique
  names          Name[]
  order          Int      @default(0)
  stats          Stat[]
  sprite         String   @default("")
  type1          String   @default("")
  type2          String?
  weight         Int      @default(0)
}

// relevant if the pokémon has a 'mega' form or specialized forms like Deoxys
// (Pikachu has a bunch of 'regional cap' forms as well)
model Form {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  pokemonId Int
  name      String
  url       String
  Pokemon   Pokemon @relation(fields: [pokemonId], references: [id])
}

// flavor text like 'seed pokémon' for Bulbasaur and evolutions
model Genus {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  pokemonId Int
  genus     String  @unique
  language  String
  Pokemon   Pokemon @relation(fields: [pokemonId], references: [id])
}

// name of the pokémon in different languages
model Name {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  pokemonId Int
  name      String
  language  String
  Pokemon   Pokemon @relation(fields: [pokemonId], references: [id])
}

// base stat of the pokémon (HP, Attack, Defence, Sp. Attack, Sp. Defence, Speed)
model Stat {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  baseStat  Int
  effort    Int
  name      String
  Pokemon   Pokemon @relation(fields: [pokemonId], references: [id])
  pokemonId Int
}
```